# Hosting by using external ip

Tags: python, hosting, ip, external

I would like to see the `Hello World!` string of the following python file from my external ip address when anyone on the internet would type in my external ip in the url bar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

cont = '''Hello world!'''

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [cont]

server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
server.serve_forever()
```

Just typing in my external ip address in my browser's url bar doesn't work. Changing the 0.0.0.0 with my external ip does not work either. How do I do this?

(BTW: The script works when I go to my internal ip address in my browser)

Comment: Are you remember to add `:8080`?   Because you're creating the server on port 8080, and your web browser will use port 80 by default.  So, `http://your.ip.address:8080`.

Comment: go to moanymyip.com and see what is your external ip, give that to people, then port-forward it to your internal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are being a router that is doing Network Address Translation (NAT), and so you need to [port forward](http://portforward.com/) in order to allow an outside machine to connect to your server.

It is also possible you are running a firewall which is blocking inbound requests.

It is also possible that your ISP blocks inbound requests on that port. You can check that easily using an [online tool](http://canyouseeme.org/).

Comment: Thank you! Your online tool returned: `
Returned Error: I could not see your service on 91.x.x.x on port (8080)
Reason: No route to host`

I went to [yougetsignal.com](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and inserted my external ip with my assigned 8080 port number. It returned that the port is closed which I assume means I need to port forward or that I am behind a firewall. Once I 'port forward', can I easily 'port backward(?)' again so I am not exposed to a security threat?

Comment: You can remove a port forward easily enough, although NAT is a hack to allow the use of less IP addresses, it is not a security system - use a firewall for security.